# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo / java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android

I'm having this error while running on my device. I've been browsing the issue and I'm pretty sure I'm not having the same issues as mentioned. Both of my activities are declared in the AndroidManifest and the intent filter is there. I have no libraries whatsoever (except v4 support library, but declaring it doesn't change the problem). I tried replacing in my Manifest `carpedujourproductions.quickpronote.MainActivity` by `.MainActivity` but still no luck. I'm running Android Studio 0.2.5 so I couldn't find how to resolve potential issues related to Java Build Path/Order and Export

I couldn't help but noticing my MainActivity's icon in the tree had a grey cross on the upper-left corner.

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{carpedujourproductions.quickpronote/carpedujourproductions.quickpronote.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "carpedujourproductions.quickpronote.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/carpedujourproductions.quickpronote-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/carpedujourproductions.quickpronote-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2281)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1263)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5124)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:110)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "carpedujourproductions.quickpronote.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/carpedujourproductions.quickpronote-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/carpedujourproductions.quickpronote-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
        ... 12 more
```

Feel free to browse through the code [here](https://github.com/DaS4ilor/QuickPronote) for AndroidManifest, MainActivity.java, FirstRun.java, etc.

Comment: It could be an Eclipse build problem when refreshing the project files. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20421764/2554058) for a possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MainActivity.java` is excluded from compile, so this class isn't included in .apk.  Remove line:

```
<file url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/src/carpedujourproductions/quickpronote/MainActivity.java" />
```

from the `excludeFromCompile` section of the `.idea/compiler.xml` file (or you can do this from IDE settings).

Comment: Thanks! I have other (minor) errors now, but you saved me on this one!

Answer (score 2):

This error could be raised with several causes, for my experience i expose two of them.

- if we have some code lines in resource files that are inserted by SVN Client like smartSVN or tortoise.

  ```
  <<<<<<< .mine
      <string name="pathConfiguration">http://jorgesys/app/config_development.xml</string>
  =======    

  >>>>>>> .r124
  ```

  <<<<<<< .mine

  removing that characters:

  ```
  <string name="pathConfiguration">http://jorgesys/app/config_development.xml</string>
  ```
- Into the `.classpath` file add the line

  ```
  <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
  ```

this is an example:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Now it works! =)

it will fix the exception

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Cleaning the project should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

If you add additional libs to your project you need to export them with your project in case that some classes excluded.

right click your project and go to Properties. Click `Java Build Path` on left panel and navigate to `Order and Export` tab. You may need to **check** the third party libs in order to add them to build path and export them to apk. Also notice that the **order** of libs are also important, the topper they are the higher properties they have when building apk.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed

```
compileOptions{
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

to

```
compileOptions{
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

and it worked like a charm.....