# Error "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:"

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

During android vogella tutorial regarding to sqlite I have encountered annoying problem with following error:

```
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider.MyTodoContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.de.vogella.android.todos-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.de.vogella.android.todos-1, /system/lib]]
```

I followed many times step by step modyfying all files to have R. class properly recreated. The very strange thing about this errror is that I have no idea why there is anything about "com.example" in "com.example.de.vogella.android". Is this some kind of standard generated name? All my packages/names/paths never started with "com.example"(In this project). I checked all files and cant find issue.

More output from LogCat:

```
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.example.de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider.MyTodoContentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider.MyTodoContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.de.vogella.android.todos-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.de.vogella.android.todos-1, /system/lib]]
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4882)
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4485)
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4425)
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider.MyTodoContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.de.vogella.android.todos-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.de.vogella.android.todos-1, /system/lib]]
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4867)
09-05 09:18:06.127: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  ... 12 more
09-05 09:18:06.156: E/ActivityThread(950): Failed to find provider info for de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider
```

In generall application starts but gets crash from the beginning with output:

```
Unfortunatelly, {AppName} has stopped.
```

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.vogella.android.todos"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/reminder"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TodosOverviewActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TodoDetailActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_todo_detail" >
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name=".contentprovider.MyTodoContentProvider"
            android:authorities="de.vogella.android.todos.contentproviderxxxxxxx" >
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have just started with android so I guese there is something trivial missing.

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**
Change of `<provider>` to:

```
<provider
            android:name=".contentprovider.MyTodoContentProvider"
            android:authorities="de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider" >
        </provider>
```

results in :

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!
```

with LogCat:

```
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.example.de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider.MyTodoContentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider.MyTodoContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.de.vogella.android.todos-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.de.vogella.android.todos-1, /system/lib]]
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4882)
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4485)
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4425)
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider.MyTodoContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.de.vogella.android.todos-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.de.vogella.android.todos-1, /system/lib]]
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4867)
09-06 02:02:38.198: E/AndroidRuntime(864):  ... 12 more
09-06 02:02:38.236: E/ActivityThread(834): Failed to find provider info for de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider
```

Comment: Off-topic: Please use the gray checkmarks on your other questions to accept answers to those questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this problem once. The code was working previously and suddenly it stopped working (crash at app startup) when I synced and built an older version of the code.

The fix was to just close and restart Eclipse and clean the project and clean all the dependent library projects. Then it started working properly again.

It's some sort of build problem in Eclipse, when refreshing the project files.

Update: In particular, if you've accidentally modified the ".classpath" file (to revert to an older version), Eclipse/Android SDK can get confused and not build the project properly. When you restart Eclipse and clean the project, Eclipse will re-modify the ".classpath" file, and build properly.

Comment: I am facing similar issue where i have system app built on eclipse now i am updating it using adb install -r(android-studio),it crashes in launch of app and goes back to previous version.Any  kind of help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Change this line in your Code :

```
<provider
        android:name="de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider.MyTodoContentProvider"
        android:authorities="de.vogella.android.todos.contentproviderxxxxxxx" >
</provider>
```

Your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget to declare the content provider in your Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

No com.example is not a standard package name, It is generated according to the **AndroidManifest.xml** file that is located at the root of the project.

At the manifest file there is an attribute called package which gives the application a unique name.

Please check the manifest file and to my best guess, fix the **package** attribute as

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.vogella.android.todos"
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly /res/AndroidManifest.xml and /bin/AndroidManigest.xml are exacly as pasted in first post - does not contain "com.example".

Comment: Would you please searc "com.example" phrase in your project and write down the results?