# RecyclerView ClassNotFound

Tags: android

I tried to add RecyclerView and CardView into my project

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
compile project(':facebook')
}
```

it compiles, but I got below exception when run it on device

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.RecyclerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/xxxx.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/xxxx, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Problem in your layout. Change

```
<RecyclerView 
   ...
```

To

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
   ...
```

If you create RecyclerView programmatically - make sure you have proper import:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
```

Comment: yeah, looks like I am using the latest buildtools and it do have the android.view.RecyclerView, so there is no error in android studio, but I am running it on a 4.4.4 device...

Comment: In my layout, I have written same, still facing same problem. In CS class I am able to find  android.support.v7.widget but not  android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Answer (score 5):

I did all what have been said in this post but nothing worked.

What did work for me:

1.Add this as say up in your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
```

2.Add the RecyclerView as a standar View and indicate the class:

```
    <view
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    />
```

3.Then add the imports:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had forgotten recyclerview was its own compile line. Didn't need to do other stuff.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for solution in 2019, you could try to change `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` for `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`. It works for me. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

you can use androidx recyclerview widget,  this works !

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/listExp"
    />
```

and import to code,

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
```

and then ready to use ,

```
 private RecyclerView recyclerViewExp;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
```

Comment: By the way, rendering in Android Studio has some isssues http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72117 http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=85118, in my case in version 1.1.0 a don't have previews for recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

in eclipse, you need to clear other(older) versions of android-support-v4.jar from other libraries which you import directly or indirectly.

for my instance ; my project(TurkRenkleri)   includes MobilePlayGround which includes appcompat library(which has a older version of support v4 jar). So i didnt get the error given below, instead i got RecyclerView ClassNotFound.

after doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26515471/1880500) , i finally got the error below, and understood problem therefore the solution(delete old jars).

```
[2015-04-29 00:59:53 - TurkRenkleri] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
 [2015-04-29 00:59:53 - TurkRenkleri] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
 [2015-04-29 00:59:53 - TurkRenkleri] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
 [2015-04-29 00:59:53 - TurkRenkleri] Versions found are:
 [2015-04-29 00:59:53 - TurkRenkleri] Path: E:\calisma alani\oyunlar\android-support-v7-appcompat\libs\android-support-v4.jar
 [2015-04-29 00:59:53 - TurkRenkleri]   Length: 621451
 [2015-04-29 00:59:53 - TurkRenkleri]   SHA-1: 5896b0a4e377ac4242eb2bc785220c1c4fc052f4
 [2015-04-29 00:59:53 - TurkRenkleri] Path: E:\calisma alani\oyunlar\RecyclerView\libs\android-support-v4.jar
 [2015-04-29 00:59:53 - TurkRenkleri]   Length: 1157388
 [2015-04-29 00:59:53 - TurkRenkleri]   SHA-1: 605c447c20ca216b5556af9f215af5d4bba1b117
 [2015-04-29 00:59:53 - TurkRenkleri] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

Make  sure  is  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Add this to app gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Then in your layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

and in your activity

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
```

and inside your onCreate

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
```

Answer (score -2):

> It is a Building problem...
>
> Yes in few cases , The code was working previously and suddenly it
>   stopped working (crash at app startup) when I synced and built an
>   older version of the code.
>
> The fix was to just close and restart Eclipse and clean the project
>   and clean all the dependent library projects. Then it started working
>   properly again.
>
> It's some sort of build problem in Eclipse, when refreshing the
>   project files.
>
> Update: In particular, if you've accidentally modified the
>   ".classpath" file (to revert to an older version), Eclipse/Android SDK
>   can get confused and not build the project properly. When you restart
>   Eclipse and clean the project, Eclipse will re-modify the ".classpath"
>   file, and build properly.

Comment: If you are going to provide an answer from another related question, please link http://stackoverflow.com/a/20421764 instead of copy+paste.