# Android Studio: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-studio, classnotfoundexception

i was busy with my app for over a week, when suddenly:

```
11-12 07:59:17.860    1653-1653/nl.test.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{nl.test.MyApp/nl.test.MyApp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "nl.test.myapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/nl.test.myapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/nl.test.myapp-2, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "nl.test.myapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/nl.test.MyApp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/nl.test.MyApp-2, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nl.test.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="nl.test.myapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".welcomewizard.WelcomeWizardIntroPage"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity android:name=".welcomewizard.WelcomeWizardPage1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity android:name=".welcomewizard.WelcomeWizardPage2"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity android:name=".welcomewizard.WelcomeWizardPage3"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity android:name=".welcomewizard.WelcomeWizardPage4"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity android:name=".welcomewizard.WelcomeWizardFinishPage"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity android:name=".CompanySelectorActivity"
            android:label="@string/compsel_actionbarlabel" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this was happening after some problems with my R.java (the id's for the views where incorrect), after rebuilding the project this problem happend

i've already tried the Invalidate Cashes/restart in the IDE File-menu

**Update 14:51**:
this is my compiler.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="CompilerConfiguration">
    <option name="DEFAULT_COMPILER" value="Javac" />
    <resourceExtensions />
    <wildcardResourcePatterns>
      <entry name="!?*.java" />
      <entry name="!?*.form" />
      <entry name="!?*.class" />
      <entry name="!?*.groovy" />
      <entry name="!?*.scala" />
      <entry name="!?*.flex" />
      <entry name="!?*.kt" />
      <entry name="!?*.clj" />
    </wildcardResourcePatterns>
    <annotationProcessing>
      <profile default="true" name="Default" enabled="false">
        <processorPath useClasspath="true" />
      </profile>
    </annotationProcessing>
  </component>
</project>
```

My MainActivity.java file (\src\main\java\nl\test\myapp\MainActivity.java) :

```
package nl.test.myapp;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import nl.test.myapp.welcomewizard.WelcomeWizardIntroPage;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setBackground(R.drawable.background_grey);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeWizardIntroPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void setBackground(int drawable){
        int currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(currentApiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
            layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(drawable));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have u forgot to import any libraries?

Comment: no import-errors (or other errors at all) in my IDE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a new project in Android studio and copied everything from the old project into the new one. Now it's working again, without any(!) modifications to the code.

Answer (score 9):

Close android studio. Navigate to the project folder. Delete all files relating to intelliJ (Android Studio) i.e

- .idea (folder)
- *.imi (files)

Also make sure that package name matches the package in the android manifest.xml.

Then reimport the project.

This happened to me because I renamed the root package and IntelliJ (android studio) didn't track this.

Comment: Perhaps you meant .iml files?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, turns out I screwed up with some final method.
Be sure to check `dalvikvm` errors in logcat output **before** the FATAL EXCEPTION. I will give you some hints on the problem. In my case, I had a final method (`isResumed`) which was already defined in the base class - causing runtime crash. Wasn't complaining at compile time.

Check the logs:

```
E/dalvikvm( 9984): Method Lcom/your/package/ui/SomeActivity;.isResumed overrides final Landroid/app/Activity;.isResumed
W/dalvikvm( 9984): failed creating vtable
...
D/AndroidRuntime( 9962): Shutting down VM
...
E/AndroidRuntime(10065): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10065): Process: com.yourpackage.ui, PID: 10065
E/AndroidRuntime(10065): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.yourpackage.ui/com.yourpackage.ui.HomeActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.yourpackage.ui.HomeActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.yourpackage.ui-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.yourpackage.ui-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
...
```

Comment: This happened to me too, when I used it with `Picasso`. I used two booleans `isFound` and `isConnected` for my own validation. Turns out this was where I was going wrong. Changing variable name to something like `is_Connected ` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this. My app had been running fine and one day it just started running into these ClassNotFoundExceptions. My code hadn't changed at all.

As far as I can tell, it ended up being a bug in the build of Android Studio. I had recently updated to the latest release on the canary channel.

Switching back to an older release on the dev channel got things working again:

1. Go into Settings / Appearance & Behavior / System Settings / Update
2. Change to Dev Channel and Check Now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem. I remembered, that previously "not enough memory" message was shown and the application uploading process could not finish, stopping on dexDebug with error. Then I released enough memory, but application started with ClassNotFoundException. 
The solution that worked for me was to delete all "build" folders in the project. I suppose that gradle can put corrupted files to "build" folder when there is not enough memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can check Multidex mechanism. The reason may be method numbers overflow.

1. Add MultiDex.install(this); to your Application:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
   }
   ```
2. and add

   ```
   afterEvaluate {
      tasks.matching {
          it.name.startsWith('dex')
      }.each { dx ->
          if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
              dx.additionalParameters = []
          }
          dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex' // enable multidex
      }
   }
   ```

to your app module's gradle.build

Comment: Upvoted!! This was the only answer that solved my problem here

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too, and none of the postings here helped.  My problem was also caused by my having renamed the root package.  My ClassNotFoundException was showing a DexPathList which was the old path to my package.  I found the cause was in my Gradle Script called "build.gradle (Module: app)" I had a line saying: applicationId "old package name".  I changed this to the new package name, did a gradle sync, and everything worked.

Comment: I also made the same mistake but didn't realize. thank you! you helped me.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know this will help you..anyway try to use application theme as @style/Theme.AppCompat..we must use as per developers forum.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >

       <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't change a thing

Comment: are you sure, you have mainactivity in the nl.test.myapp package?

Comment: try my latest answer..https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html..

Answer (score 0):

```
   try: 
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a namespace typo somewhere. Search for `MyApp` and change it to `myapp`.

Comment: Hmm then why it's complaining about `nl.test.MyApp.MainActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

Your MainActivity.java is excluded from compile, so this class isn't included in .apk. Remove line:

```
<file url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/src/nl/test/MyApp.java" />
```

from the excludeFromCompile section of the .idea/compiler.xml file (or you can do this from IDE settings).

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533054/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo-java)

Comment: please go through the link what i have added.The bug seems to be as same as yours

Comment: thanks, but i have added my compiler.xml file in my question, you can take a look

Answer (score 0):

As i can see in your Log ,

`nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/nl.test.myapp-2, /system/lib`

For that you can change your `lib` to `libs` , I did this and it resolved my problem.

you would see some error mark on project to resolve that go to project properties and java build path, Remove all the libraries from there  . You will not see this error again. :)

Answer (score 0):

When using Android Studio, please ensure that the "src" folder that contains your Java class is marked as "Source Root". Otherwise, it will not make it into the APK.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was manifest declaration of `android.app.Application` in project and actual code in module.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating an android library, you may simply have forgotten to import your library in your app build.gradle with the `implementation project` keyword :

`dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation project(':mylib-module:mymodule')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
}`

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

GO to **Build** Menu and **Clean Project**.

The above solution worked perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29821331/11480535 worked for me with the little addition that I also had to delete the `projectFilesBackup/`!