# class not found on path

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

i am working with the facebook sdk for android and i was following a tutorial. When i ran my code it says java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ftester/com.example.ftester.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.ftester.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.ftester-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.ftester-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


private static final int SPLASH = 0;
private static final int SELECTION = 1;
private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = SELECTION +1;
private boolean isResumed = false;
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];

private Session.StatusCallback callback = 
        new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, 
                SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragments[SPLASH] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);
        fragments[SELECTION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
        transaction.commit();


}





private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        if (i == fragmentIndex) {
            transaction.show(fragments[i]);
        } else {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
    }
    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        // if the session is already open,
        // try to show the selection fragment
        showFragment(SELECTION, false);
    } else {
        // otherwise present the splash screen
        // and ask the person to login.
        showFragment(SPLASH, false);
    }
 }

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    // Only make changes if the activity is visible
    if (isResumed) {
         FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        // Get the number of entries in the back stack
        int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        // Clear the back stack
        for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
            manager.popBackStack();
        }
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            // If the session state is open:
            // Show the authenticated fragment
            showFragment(SELECTION, false);
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            // If the session state is closed:
            // Show the login fragment
            showFragment(SPLASH, false);
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
    isResumed = true;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}






@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
    isResumed = false;
}
     }




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ftester"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ftester.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>

   </manifest>
```

Comment: Is MainActivity declared properly in your Manifest file?

Comment: yes, i have declared it

Comment: whats the package name where MainActivity is placed?

Comment: the package name is " com.example.ftester"

Comment: Are you sure your package name is specified as such in your MainActivity.java? I don't see that line in your source code you have pasted. Anyways, the only reason you are getting this error is because MainActivity.class is not visible to the system for some reason. Start over with a fresh new simple hello-world project. Make sure it works and then start adding all the Fragment code to the new project bit a bit. That should help :)

Comment: I started a new porject and it was working. But as soon as i changed extends Activity to FragmentActivity it crashed and says class not found

Comment: Do you have the correct android support library (support-v4.jar or support-v11.jar) imported and included in your build path?

Answer (score 0):

There's a possibility that your MainActivity.java file is not being compiled and not available in the apk file. Check and try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/18533212/3025732