# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo (...) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Hi guys am trying to compile this code from Git hub but getting the error (app crashes the moment i try to start with)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.viewpagerparallax/com.example.viewpagerparallax.MyTestActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.viewpagerparallax.MyTestActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.viewpagerparallax-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.viewpagerparallax-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

non of the stack overflow questions/solutions helped me.

Moreover when i switch to main.xml layout view it says

```
The following classes could not be found:
- com.example.viewpagerparallax (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

although the .java file exist in the same package

and here is my manifest file (I have changed the package name to com.example.viewpagerparallax.MyTestActivity  in my case )
here is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.viewpagerparallax"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.viewpagerparallax.MyTestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the link which i am following

https://github.com/MatthieuLJ/ViewPagerParallax
if u need the files please let me know.

Please Help
Thanks in advance

Comment: once clean your project and try...

Comment: Is there any third party jar file added in your code?

Comment: @ gopal Rao tried number of times no result.

Comment: @ Siddarth Vyas i downloaded the whole code nothing was mentioned
but without a jar file added ,how the code can compile am still a new to this .I dont know

Comment: download again the project and run again, i downloaded and worked fine

Comment: @ Shayan Pourvatan
Thaks for the help dude

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it.Mark all checkboxes.Click on Apply and clean the project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i can find android dependencies but not support library
do u mean the android private libraries,even then both of them are ticked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was raised because i had some code lines in resource files or Manifest.xml that are inserted by SVN Client like smartSVN or tortoise.

```
    <<<<<<< .mine
        <string name="pathConfiguration">http://jorgesys/app/config_development.xml</string>
    =======    

    >>>>>>> .r124
<<<<<<< .mine
```

So removing that lines

```
<string name="pathConfiguration">http://jorgesys/app/config_development.xml</string>
```

it will fix the exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you add additional libs to your project you need to export them with your project in case that some classes excluded.

I already answer the question, that will fix the problem with ease.
see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533054/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo-java/25682554#25682554)